# Ubuntu, freeze due booting

Tags: ubuntu, kernel

I have VPS with Ubuntu. Due system boot freeze now.

[image]

I tried boot in recovery mode, but freeze too.

[image]

I need data from this server, so is there way boot to system with SSH conection?

Thanks.

**Update.**

I tried it with `grub`, it shows me, that there is LVM on disk, it might be the problem. How can mount it in `initramfs` and then run network and ssh? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Create another VM with similar characteristics
2. Mount additional storage from the file used by your old VM for a disk storage

Hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thanks. I tried it with grub, it shows me, that there is LVM on disk, do it might be the problem. How can mount it in `initramfs` and then run network and ssh? Thanks.

Comment: Edit your VM settings, add a new storage from the file - this will imitate the presence of additional hardware. Then use software tools to analyze its partitions and mount them if you need. Perhaps the contents will be accessible in GUI due to automount. Good luck!

Comment: I am afraid I can't, because my provider dooesn;t provide, just strict devices for VPS. :/

Comment: Thanks god, there will be gparted booting, so I can connect it via lvm and copy data.